# Добавить в выборку поле с несколькими условиями

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть основной запрос, который делает определённую выборку. И к нему нужно прицепить ещё 1 поле. Вот как сейчас выглядит мой запрос:

```
select m.PIPE_NUMBER,
       m.PIPE_YEAR,
       s.WC_INSTANCE,
       r.WORKCENTER_ID,
       s.RETURN_REASON,
       m.DIAMETER,
       m.THICKNESS,
       m.MELT_NUMBER,
       m.PART_WELD,
       m.STEELMARK,
       m.VENDER,
       s.WAREHOUSE_BEFORE_MOVING,
       s.ORDER_NUM_RES || '-' || s.ORDER_ITEM_RES as res_und_order,
       s.CREATE_DATE,
       s.INSERT_OPERATOR,
       (select min(p.CREATE_DATE) keep(dense_rank first order by s.create_date desc)
          from WC_7_3_SGP s
          left join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p
            on s.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID
           and s.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR
           and s.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER
           and p.EDIT_STATE = 0
           and p.WC_INSTANCE = s.WC_INSTANCE
         where s.ORDER_NUM_RES is null
           and s.ORDER_ITEM_RES is null
           and s.EDIT_STATE = 0
           and s.PIPE_NUMBER = m.PIPE_NUMBER) as DATE_CANCEL_RESERV,
       (select min(p.INSERT_OPERATOR) keep(dense_rank first order by s.create_date desc)
          from WC_7_3_SGP s
          left join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p
            on s.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID
           and s.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR
           and s.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER
           and p.EDIT_STATE = 0
           and p.WC_INSTANCE = s.WC_INSTANCE
         where s.ORDER_NUM_RES is null
           and s.ORDER_ITEM_RES is null
           and s.EDIT_STATE = 0
           and s.PIPE_NUMBER = m.PIPE_NUMBER) as OPERATOR_PRM
  from WC_MAIN m
  left join WC_1_2_LIST l
    on m.SHOP_ID = l.SHOP_ID
   and m.PIPE_YEAR = l.PIPE_YEAR
   and m.PIPE_NUMBER = l.PIPE_NUMBER
  left join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p
    on m.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID
   and m.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR
   and m.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER
  left join WC_7_3_SGP s
    on m.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID
   and m.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR
   and m.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
  left join ROUTE_PIPE_MOVES r
    on m.SHOP_ID = r.SHOP_ID
   and m.PIPE_YEAR = r.PIPE_YEAR
   and m.PIPE_NUMBER = r.PIPE_NUMBER
 where m.EDIT_STATE = 0
   and p.EDIT_STATE = 0
   and l.EDIT_STATE = 0
   and s.EDIT_STATE = 0
   and r.EDIT_STATE = 0
   and r.ACTION = 'MOVE'
```

К основной части запрос нужно прицепить поле на следующих условиях использую case:

- Если

  1. минимальная дата пункта приёмки больше максимальной даты пункта сгп,
  2. адрес возврата is null и
  3. `s.ORDER_NUM_RES||'-'|| s.ORDER_ITEM_RES = p.ORDER_NUMBER`

  тогда создаётся нужное мне поле, допустим с названием status, и в него пишеться "Подтверждено",
- иначе: те же условия только `s.ORDER_NUM_RES||'-'|| s.ORDER_ITEM_RES <> p.ORDER_NUMBER` уже не равны тогда в поле запишется "Не подтверждено",
- иначе в поле пишется "Активно".

Не могу понять как это воткнуть среди полей. Либо очень сложная вложенность с case'ами либо не представляю.

```
select p.CREATE_DATE,
       s.CREATE_DATE,
       s.RETURN_ADDRESS,
       s.ORDER_NUM_RES || '-' || s.ORDER_ITEM_RES as res_und_order,
       p.ORDER_NUMBER
  from WC_MAIN m
  left join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p
    on m.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID
   and m.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR
   and m.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER
  left join WC_7_3_SGP s
    on m.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID
   and m.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR
   and m.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
```

Вот запрос для примера. Условия остаются теми же что я описал выше. Даты это как раз `p.CREATE_DATE` и `s.CREATE_DATE`. s это дата первого пункта, а p дата второго.

Comment: @Mike помогите пожалуйста с этим вопросом.

Comment: Комментарии пишу в том чате, что по предыдущему вопросу ...

Comment: 90% этого запроса (если не 100) не имеют отношения к делу. Постарайтесь упростить запрос, создать [воспроизводимый пример в 
 котором не будет ничего лишнего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и четко сформулировать требования. Вопросы вида: «Как сделать чтобы все заработало?» слишком широки для этого сайта

Comment: @defaultlocale думаю я вас понял, примерно это должно выглядеть по другому, добавил в вопрос ещё 1 запрос для упрощения. Он содержит парочку лишних полей, я их добавил туда  потому что они нужны в условиях для добавления нового поля с помощью case'ов. В общем для наглядности.

Comment: @defaultlocale надеюсь теперь мой вопрос понятен. Если что то ещё не понятно, пишите, я постараюсь объяснить.

Comment: @Андрей вам самим то понятно, что у вас в первом скрипте? отформатируйте нормально, чтобы было сходу понятно. При таком скрипте, как в первой части, есть только желание закрыть вкладку с вопросом.

Comment: @Андрей второй запрос иллюстративнее и ближе к делу, спасибо. Хорошо бы еще добавить Вашу попытку. Там же вроде `CASE`  с тремя условиями, которые хорошо расписаны, неясно с чем именно возникли сложности

Comment: @defaultlocale не думаю что получиться накидать вариант, там вся проблема в условии с датами. Эти даты очень сложно найти. В первом примере запроса если вы его читали, есть 2 поля формирующиеся под запросами. И там дёргается одна дата. И вот по ней + ещё по одной мне нужно как раз и сделать условие в case для нового поля. Не пойму как эту же вложенность оформить тут в case.

Comment: `select min(p.CREATE_DATE) keep(dense_rank first order by s.create_date desc) from WC_7_3_SGP s
left join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p on s.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID and s.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR and s.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER and p.EDIT_STATE = 0 and p.WC_INSTANCE = s.WC_INSTANCE
where s.ORDER_NUM_RES is null and s.ORDER_ITEM_RES is null and s.EDIT_STATE = 0 and s.PIPE_NUMBER = m.PIPE_NUMBER` Вот этот самый под запрос. Тут дёргается дата второго пункта. На основе даты первого пункта. Но разница в том что для нового поля нужно учитывать их обе. Не могу сообразить как это реализовать.

Comment: @defaultlocale возможно дату в этом под запросе можно как то сохранить.

Comment: @defaultlocale тогда было бы проще дальше с ней работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В первом примере запроса если вы его читали, есть 2 поля формирующиеся под запросами. И там дёргается одна дата. И вот по ней + ещё по одной мне нужно как раз и сделать условие в case для нового поля.

Если загвоздка только в том, чтобы использовать поля, которые выбираются подзапросами несколько раз, то попробуйте выбрать все нужные поля и обращайтесь к результату целиком:

```
select *
from (
    select m.PIPE_NUMBER,
    ... здесь весь первый запрос
) res
```

Таким образом будут доступны для работы поля, полученные в первом запросе и дальше их можно обрабатывать, добавить поле например:

```
select res.*,
       (case
            when res.DATE_CANCEL_RESERV > res.CREATE_DATE 
                 and ... еще условия
                 then 'Подтверждено'
            when ...
                 then 'Не подтверждено'
            else 'Активно'
       end) status
from (
    select m.PIPE_NUMBER,
    ... здесь весь первый запрос
) res
```